# Vue.js get element by id/ref

Tags: vue.js

I have a custom component called 'menu-entry':

```
<menu-entry v-for="field in fields" :id:"field.id" :ref="field.id" v-bind:key="field.id" v-bind:class="[classArray]" v-bind:field="field" v-on:clicked="menuEntryClicked">
</menu-entry>
```

I need to get one of them (for example field.id = 2) and remove an item from the classArray.
this.$refs[2] is working for HTML elements, but not for custom elements.
this.$el.querySelector isnt working either.

is there another way to remove an item from the classArray of a specific element?

Comment: `:id:"field.id"` should be `:id="field.id"`

Comment: yes, but thats not the problem. i changed it. in the mounted() function i try to console.log(this.$el.querySelector('#2')) or console.log(this.$el.querySelector('2')) but it says: Error in mounted hook: "SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': '#2' is not a valid selector."

Comment: Can you include the component definition this template is bound to?  Sounds like if you want to remove an item from `classArray` you just remove it from the data property and Vue will handle the binding.  It's not clear why you're resorting to querying the DOM.

Comment: component definition:
`<template>
  <button type="button" v-on:click="buttonClicked">{{ field.name }}</button>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ['field'],
  data () {
    return {
      fieldsDone: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    buttonClicked () {
      this.$emit('clicked', { field: this.field })
    }
  }
}
</script>`

Comment: hey can u edit the question and make more easier to understand?And please put more code!In order to get correct responses please

Comment: ["an ID should start with a letter for compatibility"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Answer (score 0):

> Your question it is not clear but you are trying to set id and ref to `field.id` so following this logic it is not necessary to do though.

*You can just send the id to the method you are executing like below:*

```
<menu-entry 
  v-for="field in fields" 
  v-bind:key="field.id" 
  v-bind:class="[classArray]" 
  v-bind:field="field" 
  v-on:clicked="menuEntryClicked(field.id)" // <= send the id here
  >
</menu-entry>
```

*I am not sure if i helped but regarding your question, now you can figoure out which id of element is clicked and remove it from classArray or whatever you want*

Answer (score 0):

`2` is not a valid id selector when you use `document.querySelector('#2')`; maybe you can use `document.getElementById('2')` instead - it can work.